# Dynamic link object has no url

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I created the DynamicLink for my firebase project when I am trying to receive the link I am getting "That's weird. My dynamic link object has no url".

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL{
                   print("Incoming URL is \(incomingURL)")
                   let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL)
                   {(dynamicLink, error) in
                       guard error == nil else{
                           print("Found an error! \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                           return
                       }
                       if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink{
                        self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
                       }
                   }
                   if linkHandled{
                       return true

                   }
                   else{
                       return false
                   }
               }
               return false
    }


 func handleIncomingDynamicLink(_ dynamicLink: DynamicLink){
        guard let url = dynamicLink.url else{
            print("That's weird. My dynamic link object has no url")
            return
        }
        print("Your incoming link parameter is\(url.absoluteString)")
}
```

Comment: I am facing similar issues, mine works during debug but is nil when I make a release build, did you find out a solution?

Comment: same problem here did anyone found any solution, please.

Comment: did you find out any solution ?

Comment: did anyone found any solution? Please update here.

Comment: @Madhuri Doppalapudi any solutions ?

Answer (score 4):

**After checking all the blogs and posted this issue on firebase, I didn't find any solution for this but I came up with this concrete solution and it will work definitely**

---

here: *`dynamicLinkURL`* is your main dynamic link and *`shortHandURL`* is your deeplink URL which is associated with your dynamic link. I hope the below snippet will help you.

---

```
func dynamicLinkhandler(_ dynamicLinkURL: URL, onCompletion: @escaping(_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: dynamicLinkURL) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Found Error \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription)))")
            return
        }
        guard let shortHandURL = response?.url, shortHandURL != dynamicLinkURL else {
            print("Thats Weird, my dynamic link has no URL")
            onCompletion(false)
            return
        }
        onCompletion(true)
    }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the bundle id you set up in the dynamic link wizard creation within the firebase console it's the one you are running the app into.

I have three different bundle ids (dev, enterprise, production) and, for instance, if a set in the link the production bundle id but the app runs the dev bundle id, instead of returning back some error it returned an honest `dynamicLink` object but with a nil value in the `url`.